# Using Law of iterated expectations, I want to calculate mean of Y, E(Y)

Tags: r, expected-value, joint-distribution

I obtain insights into calculating the conditional mean and
variance of Y given X, denoted as E(Y|X) and Var(Y|X) respectively. Building upon this
knowledge, I want to answer the follow-up question using the same joint probability
distribution f(x, y):

[image]

I want to answer the question which I did by using R but Im not sure I got it right. Maybe my question is for Stack Overflow but Im open to a non-R answer as well. The most important is to verify the correctness.

• E(Y |X = 0) = 1

• E(Y |X = 1) = 3/4

• V ar(Y |X = 0) = 1/2

• V ar(Y |X = 1) = 11/16

• Cov(X, Y ) = −1/16

A) Using the Law of Iterated Expectations (i.e., E(Y ) = E(E(Y |X))), derive the mean of
Y, E(Y).

```
# Given probabilities
px <- c(4/8, 4/8)
# Given conditional expectations
EY_X0 <- 1
EY_X1 <- 3/4

# Calculate E(Y)
EY <- sum(px * c(EY_X0, EY_X1))
EY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of conditional expectation of
Y given X to verify your answers
$$
 E(Y|X = 0) = \sum_{y} y \cdot P(Y=y|X=0) = 0 \cdot \frac{f(0,0)}{f_{X}(0)} + 1 \cdot \frac{f(0,1)}{f_{X}(0)} + 2 \cdot \frac{f(0,2)}{f_{X}(0)} \\=
 0 \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{4}{8}} + 1 \cdot \frac{\frac{2}{8}}{\frac{4}{8}} + 2 \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{4}{8}}=1
$$

$$
    E(Y|X = 1) = \sum_{y} y \cdot P(Y=y|X=1) = 0 \cdot \frac{f(1,0)}{f_{X}(1)} + 1 \cdot \frac{f(1,1)}{f_{X}(1)} + 2 \cdot \frac{f(1,2)}{f_{X}(1)} \\=
 0 \cdot \frac{\frac{2}{8}}{\frac{4}{8}} + 1 \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{4}{8}} + 2 \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{4}{8}} =\frac{3}{4}
   $$

**For the rest, you can use the definitions below to verify your answers.**

$$
    Var(Y|X = 0) = \sum_{y} (y - E(Y|X = 0))^2 \cdot P(Y=y|X=0) 
   $$

$$
    Var(Y|X = 1) = \sum_{y} (y - E(Y|X = 1))^2 \cdot P(Y=y|X=1)
   $$

$$Cov(X, Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)
$$

where
$$E(X) = \sum_{x} x \cdot f_{X}(x)$$
$$E(Y) = \sum_{x} y\cdot f_{Y}(y)$$
$$E(XY) = \sum_{x}\sum_{y} xy \cdot f(x,y)$$

Comment: so 3/4 is the correct answer?

Comment: @firmo23 That is right, $E(Y|X=1)=\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Thank you can I create a question for the other 3?

Comment: basically me code seems correct since I found 1 and 3/4 and then EY <- sum(px * c(EY_X0, EY_X1))=0.875

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform these calculations with R, you can use the package `rje` to get the conditional distributions, and then the package `discreteRV` to get the expectations and the variances of these conditional distributions. Note that `rje` assumes that the domain of a distribution is always `{1, 2, 3, ...}`, so you have to deal with that.

```r
library(rje) # to use the conditionTable function
library(discreteRV) # to compute expectations and variances

# joint distribution of (x1, x2), on {1, 2} x {1, 2, 3}
probs <- rbind(c(1, 2, 1), c(2, 1, 1)) / 8

# conditional distribution of x2 given x1=1 (i.e. conditional distribution of y given x=0)
cprobs <- conditionTable(probs, 2, 1, 1)

# domain of x2
domain_x2 <- c(0, 1, 2)

# define a random variable whose law is the conditional distribution of x2 given x1=1
cx2 <- RV(domain_x2, cprobs)

# get the expectation E(x2 | x1=1)
E(cx2)

# get the variance Var(x2 | x1=1)
V(cx2)
```

To deal with the fact that the `x1` of `rje` is distributed on `{1, 2, 3}` while your `x` is distributed on `{0, 1, 2}`, I would define a function mapping the domain of `x` to the domain of `x1`:

```r
f <- function(i) i + 1
```

Then you can do:

````r
cprobs <- conditionTable(probs, 2, 1, f(0))
```
````

Comment: i think i have already done it correctly